# What is the difference between below pieces of React code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

First one:-

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
),document.getElementById('root'));
```

Second one:-

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector(".container")
);
```

What I would like to know is that what specifically will be the difference in doing `document.querySelector(".container")` and `document.getElementById('root')` ?

Comment: do you mean document.querySelector(".root") or document.getElementById('root') in the question?

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById('root')` gets the DOM element from your HTML with `id root` whereas `document.querySelector(".container")` gets the first element from HTML with `class container`

According to the MDN docs:

> **document.querySelector()**
>
> Returns the first Element within the document that matches the
>   specified selector, or group of selectors, or null if no matches are
>   found.
>
> **document.getElementById()**
>
> Returns a reference to the element by its ID; the ID is a string which
>   can be used to uniquely identify the element, found in the HTML id
>   attribute.

So,

in **first case** your React App will be rendered within the DOM element with `id root` whereas in **second case** it will be rendered in the first DOM element with class `container`

Answer (score 1):

If you meant difference between difference in doing document.querySelector(".container") and document.querySelector(".root"),

Then

`document.querySelector(".root")` --> renders your react code in all elements with class "root"

`document.querySelector(".container")` --> renders your react code in all elements with class "container"

If you meant difference between difference in doing document.querySelector(".container") and document.getElementById('root') in the question.

Then

`document.getElementById('root')` --> renders your react code in element with id "root"

`document.querySelector(".container")` --> renders your react code in all elements with class "container"